# Shortest route on Google Maps

Tags: travel

Looking for an app or tool or algorithm which helps find the optimal order of start, end pairs which results the shortest route between locations. If I have a minibus and people would travel with my bus, they pay for the route to go from A to B. If solution is a high level solution it should integrate with Google Maps.

Comment: I do find it odd/annoying that Google Maps can't just do this itself. I had a satnav back in 2004 [a Garmin iQ360] which could do this, so it can't be that processor-intensive. Wish you luck.

Comment: I do remember the irritating bit, though… if you didn't drive through the exact point it considered an intermediate waypoint, it wouldn't direct you to the next point until you did;)

Comment: This is similar to the [traveling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem). One of its real-life implementations is called single-vehicle routing. There are apps that tackle this, but I haven't tried any of them so I can't make a recommendation. If you're using Android, use this search: https://play.google.com/store/search?q=vehicle%20routing&c=apps